# Module "QtCanvas3D" is not installed error on Android device

Tags: android, qt, installation, qml, qtquick2

Have followed the QtCanvas3D installation from source procedure outlined [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-getting-started.html).

Doesn't seem to install anything in Qt's Android subdirectory on my development desktop (Mac OSX) and I get the

> module not installed

log when I deploy from Qt Creator to a device (build/run is otherwise fine with the desktop kit).

On the other hand, in addition to the "bundle libraries" deployment setting have also tried "use Ministro", which doesn't find the module either.

So perhaps I am also missing a `qt+=...` in the `.pro` file or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out QtCanvas3D is fully incorporated in the latest July release Qt 5.5 and my installation problem was specific to the older 5.4 release.

Everything works fine out of the box under the latest release.